# "+" or "-" as separator in URL?

Tags: url, seo, friendly-url, separator, url-design

Most websites use `-` (like Stack Overflow) but most PHP frameworks generate `+` encoded URLs.

So, what is the best for SEO? Use `+` or `-` as separators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A plus is the simplified encoding for a space (used if %20 is not used, though both are equally valid).  The '-' has no special meaning in URL encoding and will be decoded as a '-', where '+' will be decoded to a space.

Sites like stack overflow must be translating spaces to '-' to *generate* the URL (as opposed to encode the URL).

See the wikipedia article on [URL Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for more details.

Oh, and to directly answer the question, neither is better or worse for SEO.

Answer (score 6):

`+` and `-` are not equal.

The plus sign is part of the [URI encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) spec. as a reserved character. In particular the plus is used as a [shorthand notation for a space](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html) in the query string (search for "Query strings" and read the information below that heading).

This may lead to in encoding problem where one urlencoding system may use [standard percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), where as another would use [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738) URL encoding. So there could be a missmatch between the type of URL string returned. Thus you would have encode any URL which has a '+' as a significant character, and also decode the ensuing URL.

I would suggest as a best practice to not use any reserved characters as a critical part of your URL (read not the querystring) and convert spaces to '-' (dashes). As it could lead to unpredictable results in the future.

I would agree that it probably won't make a SEO difference... as long as the page is browse-able and the content (which is what matters) is index-able by the SE.

Answer (score 3):

according to SEOmoz in one of their blog [post](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/11-best-practices-for-urls) regarding URL best practices, hyphens separate best, followed by underscores, and then the pluses (+).

> When creating URLs with multiple words
>   in the format of a phrase, hyphens are
>   best to separate the terms (e.g.
>   /brands/dolce-and-gabbana/), followed
>   (in order) by, underscores (_), pluses
>   (+) and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

the - character is used as part of the [permalink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink) format.  Typically, permalinks use them in place of spaces but only as part of a title for a forum post or blog article.